# Prove that software works via SOCKS

Tags: iptables, firewall, testing

## Intro

I have ruby software that utilizes a network during its execution.

Recently I got feedback from a user who works behind a firewall and use SOCKS, this software doesn't work for him

So I need to simulate this situation to check which part of my software doesn't respect `HTTP_PROXY` environment variables

## What I have tried

I tried to simulate this firewall with `iptables` (inside docker):

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install iptables

export SOCKS5_PROXY_HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[1]
export SOCKS5_PROXY_PORT=ppp

iptables -A INPUT -s $SOCKS5_PROXY_HOST -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $SOCKS5_PROXY_HOST -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

env HTTP_PROXY=$SOCKS5_PROXY_HOST:$SOCKS5_PROXY_PORT ruby my_script.rb
```

## Problem

For some reason, this approach doesn't work and I getting:

- `Proxy CONNECT aborted` or
- `Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port pppp: Connection timed out`

Notes:

- [1] I've used IP address (not domain name) for `SOCKS` proxy
- [2] I've used different random public SOCKS proxies before applying `iptable` rules they all were reachable
- [3] Ruby Open-URI API respect `HTTP_PROXY` environment variables https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html, but maybe some third-party code doesn't.

## Questions

1. Is that an acceptable approach: trying to "simulate" firewall with `iptables`?
2. What this problem may appear is it something SOCKS specific, or misconfiguration in my `iptables`?
3. Maybe there is a better approach to achieve the same goal: test software to be working through SOCKS proxy only, without 'direct' connections?

Comment: It sounds like you have not written support for SOCKS into your program. This is not something we can help with.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the reply. Actually, Ruby respect `HTTP[S]_PROXY` environment variables https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html. And the ruby script definitely tries to connect to SOCKS proxy because in the error message I see the IP of the proxy. I have an assumption that maybe `iptables`'s rules too restrictive

Comment: HTTP(S) proxies are completely different to SOCKS proxies. The protocol is completely different so they cannot be interchanged. It requires special support in your program to connect via SOCKS, e.g. via [SOCKSSocket class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/SOCKSSocket.html).

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the answer, I didn't know that. if you will write an answer I will approve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot [@michael-hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) for comments.

Short answers to my own questions:

1. This approach works perfectly
2. Issue on `ruby` side `HTTP_PROXY` accepts only HTTP[S] proxies (it doesn't handle SOCKS proxy as `curl` does)
3. Probably `iptable` the simplest one

More details related to programming:

- My software use [`git`](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git) gem which doesn't handle `HTTP_PROXY` and any proxy needs to be set up explicitly. [Good guide how this can be accomplished](https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765)
- [`socksify`](https://github.com/astro/socksify-ruby) can help to add support easily